# How to disable SortMode in dynamically load table?

Tags: vb.net, datagrid

Actually i have an application where the user is able to load an excel file to it and that excel file will be shown in a DataGrid.

Now i would implement a method where the user will be able to select different interesting columns by clicking it but the issue is that i get the error "SortMode can't be automatic when SelectionMode is set to FullColumnSelect"

if i set other SelectionMode all works fine but i need the "FullColumnSelect". I've yet read in other question that i should disable SortMode for each column but the issue is that the columns doesn't exist till the user load the excel file.

```
        Dim myTableName = con.GetSchema("Tables").Rows(0)("TABLE_NAME")


        Dim sqlquery As String = String.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}]", myTableName)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(sqlquery, con)
        da.Fill(dt)
        dt.Rows.Remove(dt.Rows(0))
        MetroGrid1.DataSource = dt 'App crash here

        con.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the SortMode programmatically by looping through all the columns after the user has loaded the excel file.

```
  '---> load the grid

  dg1.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect

  For Each col As DataGridViewColumn In dg1.Columns
     col.SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
  Next
```

Comment: @IgorMytyuk That is a different question. Ask a new question about setting `.DataSource` and post the appropriate code.

Comment: @Mary actually i mean that i get the error "SortMode can't be automatic when SelectionMode is set to FullColumnSelect" after i load the grid and i'm loading the grid via Grid.DataSource